# Pass asp.net repeater items to javascript array

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I am building a quick web app to display locations markers on google maps from sql server database. On my, aspx page I have a repeater control that displays the lat long of the locations in the database.

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptMarkers">
     <ItemTemplate>
         title: '<%# Eval("LocationName")%>'<br />
         lat : '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>' <br />
         long : '<%# Eval("Longitude") %>
     </ItemTemplate>

     <SeparatorTemplate>
         ,
     </SeparatorTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Now what I need guidance with is , how to pass the values returned in both 
`'<%# Eval("Latitude")%>'` and `<%# Eval("Latitude") %>` into a javascript array. So that I can use the values in the javascript array to build map  markers. I know how to display the markers in google map with when I get the javascript lat long arrays. Only using the values from the repeater to build the javascript array is my challenge

Answer (score 0):

I'm Just modifying your code .
take data in label control , like this

```
long : <asp:Label ID="lblLongitude" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Longitude") %>'></asp:Label><br />

lat : <asp:Label ID="lblLatitude" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Latitude") %>'></asp:Label><br />
```

then get all data in Js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var Longitude= [];
            var Latitude= [];
            $('*[id^=rptMarkers_lblLongitude]').each(function () {
                Longitude.push($(this).html());
            });

           $('*[id^=rptMarkers_lblLatitude]').each(function () {
                Latitude.push($(this).html());
            });

        });
```

Comment: -1 for using label controls. -1 for pushing what into separate arrays, when it would make sense to push the pair of values into a single array.

Answer (score 0):

How are you binding data to the repeater? I guess you have some kind of data source. Try this:

```
<script type="text\javascript">
var location = [];
<% foreach(var elm in dataSource) %>
<%{ Response.Write("location.push({'lat': " + elm.Latitude + " , 'long': " + elm.Longitude + "});"); }%>
```

If you have to use a repeater, change the code like this:

```
<script type="text\javascript">
  var location = [];
</script>
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptMarkers">
<ItemTemplate>
    title: '<%# Eval("LocationName")%>'<br />
    lat : '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>' <br />
    long : '<%# Eval("Longitude") %>'
<script type="text\javascript">
   location.push({'lat': '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>', 'long': '<%# Eval("Longitude") %>'});
</script>
 </ItemTemplate>

 <SeparatorTemplate>
     ,
 </SeparatorTemplate>
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use a repeater. Create an anonymous array of values then use the JavaScriptSerializer to create the array.

say your dataset is called `data` & contains objects with properties as you've used above.

```
var j = new JavaScriptSeializer()
var result = j.Serialize(data.Select(i=>new { title=i.LocationName, lat=i.Latitude, lon=i.Longitude }));
```

Then in your JavaScript code block

```
var location = <%=result%>;
```

Even better would be to use the JSON.Net serializer ([site](http://json.net), [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)) but that might be overkill for one small function